# toggle svg circle color with checkbox

Tags: html, css, svg, checkbox, toggle

I would like a toggle button that changes the color of a svg, a circle in this case. I am able make a checkbox that changes the color of text purely in HTML and CSS, but it is not working with an svg.

Here is the code that works for text.

```
<label for="element-toggle">click me to toggle color</label>
<input id="element-toggle" type="checkbox" />

<div id="toggled-element">My color will be toggled</div>
```

```
label[for=element-toggle] {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}

#toggled-element {
  color: green;
}

#element-toggle:checked ~ #toggled-element {
  color: red;
}
```

Here is my attempt to use the same logic to change the color of an svg circle instead of text (this doesn't work)

```
<label for="element-toggle">click me to toggle color</label>
<input id="element-toggle" type="checkbox" />

<svg viewBox="0 0 40 30">
  <circle id="toggled-element" cx="1" cy="1.2" r="1" />
</svg>
```

```
label[for=element-toggle] {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}

#toggled-element {
  fill: green;
}

#element-toggle:checked ~ #toggled-element {
  fill: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrong element was being targeted...

I switched the `id="toggled-element"` to the `svg` as opposed to the `circle` to demonstrate.

This `#element-toggle:checked~#toggled-element` actually selects the `svg` by way of the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator).

```css
label[for=element-toggle] {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}

#toggled-element {
  fill: green;
}

#element-toggle:checked~#toggled-element {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="element-toggle">click me to toggle color</label>
<input id="element-toggle" type="checkbox" />

<svg viewBox="0 0 40 30" id="toggled-element">
  <circle cx="1" cy="1.2" r="1" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can directly select the `svg` and fill it with `green` color as:

```
svg {
  fill: green;
}
```

**2)** You have to use `fill` to fill the color in `svg` as:

```
#element-toggle:checked ~ svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

```css
label[for=element-toggle] {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}

svg {
  fill: green;
}

#element-toggle:checked ~ svg {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="element-toggle">click me to toggle color</label>
<input id="element-toggle" type="checkbox" />

<svg viewBox="0 0 40 30">
    <circle id="toggled-element" cx="1" cy="1.2" r="1" />
  </svg>
```